# Setting $RecursionLimit across all parallel kernels

Tags: parallelization, recursion

I'm trying to optimize an elliptic curve factoring method by running it in parallel. There is a recursive step which required me to set the recursion limit higher than 256, however when I try and run it in parallel apparently the `$RecursionLimit` on each different kernel isn't changed.

Here's part of the output:

```
In[76]:= ParallelECFactor[2418059292539721278076064468260051655561,1000,40]
(kernel 4) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.
(kernel 3) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.
(kernel 2) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.
(kernel 1) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.
(* and many more *)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As sebhofer pointed out, my previous solution didn't work — a fact that I missed because I wrote it without an mma to test. The users who voted for it also must've missed it, because on the surface it looks like a straightshot answer, but no. So, here's Jackson's solution **that works** — Use `ParallelEvaluate` as:

```
ParallelEvaluate[$RecursionLimit = 10^6]
```

---

Here's my previous solution that **doesn't work**, but I'm leaving it here so that others will not try something similar.

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity},
    SetSharedVariable[$RecursionLimit]
    (* your parallel code *)
]
```

Using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html) allows you to temporarily modify `$RecursionLimit` so that the global value is unaffected and[`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetSharedVariable.html) declares that the variable's value is synchronized across all kernels.

Comment: Yea I think that would work. As soon as you posted that I realized I could just do this:     ParallelEvaluate[$RecursionLimit = 10^6]

Comment: R.M: Your code does not work for me (version 8.0.4)! ParallelEvaluate[$RecursionLimit = 10^6] does work though.

Comment: @sebhofer Oh dear. Thanks for pointing that. I wrote it without mma at hand, and did not catch the error. Apparently, the parallel kernels don't see the modified value. I'll try to fix it later or if not, I'll delete it.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that, at least on Windows or Mac, setting `$RecursionLimit` as high as $10^6$ is liable to crash the kernel(s) due to stack overflow. On Linux it should be okay since there the stack can grow as large as necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's because setting a shared variable isn't the same as doing `DistributeDefinitions`. Shared variables are read from the master kernel whenever they're referenced in the subkernels using a callback. `$RecursionLimit` is treated specially by the kernel; its value can only be either an integer 20 or greater, or `Infinity`. This excludes setting its value to the expression that performs the callback. Using `DistributeDefinitions` would have worked, however.

Comment: @OleksandrR. That was the next thing I tried when `SetSharedVariable` failed. While it doesn't give an error, it doesn't respect the new value of `$RecursionLimit` either. For example: `$RecursionLimit = Infinity;
DistributeDefinitions[$RecursionLimit];
ParallelTable[{$RecursionLimit, i}, {i, 10}]`

Comment: Sorry--works in 7, not in 8 (due to what I would consider a bug). Hackish workaround: ``Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity, Parallel`Parallel`Private`$ourExcludedContexts = {}}, DistributeDefinitions[$RecursionLimit, DistributedContexts -> {"System`"}]; ParallelEvaluate[$RecursionLimit]]``

Comment: Sorry guys! Wasn't aware of all the responses. @Albert Retey I had tried to post my solution as an answer to my own question after I realized it worked, but I guess there was a block that didn't allow me to. (R.M) Glad you and (sebhofer) were able to figure out what was going on, at first glance I definitely thought your solution would've done the trick. (Oleksandr R.) I agree, it's probably not a good idea to set it that high but I'm usually even more reckless and set it to Infinity. My program probably only required it to be around 2000.